# executing stored procedure for identity in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure as

```
create procedure proc1

 @name varchar(20),
 @age int,
 @salary int

 as

 insert into employee(name,age,salary) values(@name, @age, @salary);
```

When I try to execute it using

```
exec proc1 'Tom',25,100000;
```

It gives me an error stating `'@id' parameter is not supplied.`

@id is the identity of the table. How do i modify the stored procedure to include the identity?

Comment: `@id` is a parameter somewhere, not a column. Suspect there's more code involved than shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

That error message means that your stored procedure is probably not as you think it is.

It must be already expecting a parameter called `@id` (unless the error is emanating from a trigger on the table).

Double check the stored procedure definition, check that you don't have 2 similar stored procedures in different schemas and check for triggers.

Comment: Let's suppose, I have an id field which is an identity. How would I modify this existing stored procedure to accommodate this identity?

Comment: @user1212 - You don't. `identity` values are managed by SQL Server. You don't supply an explicit value usually.